# Partial derivative of an integral from zero to infinity

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

How would one go about taking the derivative of this integral?
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial C_T} \int_{0}^{\infty} U(C_T)e^{-\delta t}dt$$

Comment: Try [using MathJaX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10164) and Leibniz integral rule.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks @KM101 for the edits!

Comment: No problem! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} U(C_T)e^{-\delta t}dt=U(C_T)\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\delta t}dt=\frac{U(C_T)}{\delta}
$$
and
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial C_T} \int_{0}^{\infty} U(C_T)e^{-\delta t}dt=\frac{U'(C_T)}{\delta}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer and showing the first steps!